# How to find and replace a string in a block of text?

Tags: javascript, replace

Given a block of string like:

```
var copy = "Hello world what is the day @James Bond blah bah blah blah...";
```

Using jQuery/JS, given:

```
var term = "James Bond";
var id = "XXXXXX";
```

How can I find all matches with `'@' + term` and return the something like this:

```
"Hello world what is the day @[XXXXXX:James Bond] blah bah blah blah..."
```

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use replace function:

```
var term = "James Bond", id = "XXXXXXX";
"Hello world what is the day @James Bond blah bah blah blah...".replace("@"+term, "@["+id+":"+term+"]");
```

Comment: This seems to work as expected: http://jsfiddle.net/DPh8Y/ what part isn't working for you?

Comment: There was a wrong concatenation issue. `id"+:"` instead of `id+":"`. Just edited my post.

Answer (score 1):

```
var toReplace = "@" + term
var replaceWith = "@[" + id + ":" + term + "]"
```

From there you should be able to use a normal string replacing function.